# Find substring in a array using jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays

Is there a way to find a substring in an array using jquery without iterating through all the elements?

I have an array

```
arr = ["tree","bird"];
```

without iterating through all the elements, can i pop the element having "ird" substring?

Comment: Why don't you want to iterate through the elements?

Comment: I don't see how you could without iterating actually...

Comment: Not for a substring search, no.  If you wanted to search for the entire element, you could use the `indexOf()` method.  (err, that is, if we were talking about plain JS and not jQuery)

Comment: Any pre-made function you used would probably just iterate through the list anyway.

Comment: The only way to do that is creating a whole different data structure, which would index chars (substrings), somewhat like a **trie**.

Comment: One option that iterates through the elements behind the scene: `var matched = $.grep(arr, function(elem) {
   return elem.indexOf('ird') > -1;
});` http://jsfiddle.net/dgejV/

Comment: What is the issue, here? Lines of code?! Performance?!

Comment: yea the issue is performance as its a large array containing data back from 1930

Comment: @user2146515 A string operation is much slower than array operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the issue is **performance** *as its a large array containing data back from 1930*, unless you are doing something like an autocomplete (which will require a re-search everytime the user types a char), **your biggest problem will be data-transfer** rather than client-side processing.

Either way, if it's a big bunch of data, **don't send to the client**. Implement a service that will do the calculation, retrieve and send the result back to you.

On server-side (or if you are really obsessive about implementing in client-side), if performance is poor while iterating through the array (or selecting the database?), your best bet is a [**Trie-like data structure**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) (it is the most common way of implementing substring search for scenarios like auto-complete).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to know if the substring appears, you can do something like:

```
var arr = ["tree", "bird"];
arr.join("|").match(/tree/); //The "|" is to make sure that the substring is not formed by 2 different words
```

Btw, this is pure Javascript, you don't need JQuery for that.

You won't be able to "pop" the element out of the array though, for that you'll have to get it's index and for that, you'll have to iterate over the array.

Comment: But then you cannot pop the element with the substring.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, no.

But if you are concerned about iterating through the whole list, you can use a for loop which you break out of as soon as you find a match.